# Should a function returned by a React Hook be wrapped in useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When you have a hook that returns a function should you wrap the function in useCallback to make sure a new reference is not created unnecessarily?

My thought process is if that function was used by another hook in a dependency array, the new function reference would cause the 2nd hook to trigger even when nothing changes.  Should a hook  only change it's output when it had a reason to change, or is it alright if a hook is noisy?

```
function useExample(someParam) {

  // ...

  const onChange = () => { /*some operation*/ }

  return { onChange }
}
```

```
function Component(props) {

  

  const { onChange } = useExample(props)

  useEffect(() => 
    //Some action
  , [onChange])

  // ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `useEffect` hook, or rather, the react-hooks linting rule, can't possibly know the origin of the callback function returned from the other function other than that it sees only a function declared external to the `useEffect` hook.

The decision to memoize this callback is entirely up to you and the specific use case.

I'm assuming your actual use case isn't as trivial as an effect that *only* calls the callback, though, so there are probably other dependencies.

If the additional "noise" of the effect running each render cycle when `callback` is a new reference doesn't cause any undesirable then it is probably ok. Otherwise, yes, memoize the `callback` to provide a stable reference for the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: exactly, I'd suggest you put some logs into useExample(props) and after, to see how many times is rerendering. 

While your props and your state keeps the same nothing will rerender, but if some of your props or state change will trigger a rerender and will pass through your useExample with the new props and return a new onChange .. in some cases your fn didnt mutate by those props but is still a new ref and will trigger a new rerender by the useEffect. 

If you don't want it you should wrap the onChange into useCallback to freeze the reference on mounting and that will avoid it.